# React Native - setState undefined on passing data

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So I'am trying to pass some data or items from screen to screen upon tapping the send button. However this.setState on my "_onPress" seems to work as it should be, upon tapping the send button the alert displays "undefined". And when I check the child screen I contains nothing.

Please help me to know what I'am missing here.

Here is my code:

ModalScreen.js

```
export default class ModalScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
        };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
            OG_id: nextProps.id,          // This id and price came from another parent screen,
            OG_price: nextProps.price     // making the screen after this the grandchild.
        })
    }

_onPress = (OG_id, OG_price) => {
    this.setState({
        Set_id: OG_id,
        Set_price: OG_price
    });
    alert(OG_id, OG_price)
    console.log(this._onPressModal)
};

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Modal
                animationType = 'slide'
                visible = { this.state.modalVisible }
                onRequestClose={() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text>{this.state.OG_id}</Text>
                            <Text>{this.state.OG_price}</Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                             onPress = { () => { this._onPress() } }>  // Send button
                                <Text>Send</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                             onPress = {() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}>
                                <Text>Close</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Settlement.js

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            Det_id: nextProps.Set_id,
            Det_price: nextProps.Set_price
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Settlement</Text>
                <Text>{ this.state.Det_id }</Text>
                <Text>{ this.state.Det_price }</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

screenshots:

[image: ModalScreen]

[image: Alert / Undefined]

[image: Settlement]

**EDIT:**

Whenever I change "prop" to "state" on my Settlement.js and then declare the in my ModalScreen.js like;

```
    <View>
        <Modal>
            <View>
                <View>
                     ....
                     ....
                </View>
                <Settlement
                Set_id = { this.state.OG_id }       // Settlement
                Set_price = { this.state.OG_price }
            />
            </View>
        </Modal>
    </View>
```

It does display the expected data but it doesn't display it in the expected screen, instead it displays in the screen. I have read many questions about passing data through screens or component and I notice some developer suggest to use .bind but I already tried it and nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: function parameter is not passed when calling on click

Comment: Can you specify sir? I'm so sorry, I', just starting to learn react native.

Comment: Can you please describe the flow of your application once as it seems a bit messy above?

Comment: Sorry sir if it looks messy. Ok so, my target is to have a modal with items(from api) passed from its parent(I already did this part), now from this modal I need to pass down again the items from modal to its child(which is the Settlement.js) once the user tap/click the send button. That's it, example: If I tap the send button with "Chicken Alffredo" and "149" in the modal, it should be shown/display in the settlement.js as list of order. (but don't mind the list of order for now I just have to know how to properly to pass the items to other screen)

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing in any arguments to `_onPress` in `ModalScreen.js` so when you click that button you are setting both state properties to undefined.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = { () => { this._onPress('some', 'data') } }>
```

Also, unless you will be manipulating the data in `Settlement.js` you probably just want to leave it as props, rather than setting it to state.

```
// Settlement.js
export default class Settlement extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Settlement</Text>
                <Text>{ this.props.Det_id }</Text>
                <Text>{ this.props.Det_price }</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't see any `TextInput`, but if you are trying to set one up check out the [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) docs.

Comment: What do you mean by 'some', 'data' sir? I tried to input my "Set_id" and "Set_price" in my this._onPress just like you do and then I change the state to props in my Settlement.js, now the alert display the data but it still not sending it to my Settlement.js.

Comment: Also in my console.log(you can see I have one in my _onPress) displays undefined when I click my send button.

Comment: In your console you log this._onPressModal but where in your code is it? I think you should paste the complete code here as I can also not see any text input here. Also componentWillReceiveProps is only called when the props to the component change. For setting the initial state you should do that in the constructor.